# Parsing complex type element in xsd and create xml file

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-parsing

I have an XSD file. I need to create XML file for only complex type inside XSD at runtime.

I am able to find the complex type inside the XSD file. But i am not able to parse it into  XML file.

Actually there are several XML files created in basis of this XSD files. And if any xml file is deleted i need to restore it from XSD at runtime.

Please help i am a new bee at XSD.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSD file describes the structure of an XML file, but not its content - usually there are many different XML files, with different content, corresponding to the same XSD. E.g. for

```
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

valid XML can be

```
<test a="something" b="something else"/>
```

but also

```
<test a="" b="2012"/>
```

and even

```
<test/>
```

How are you going to decide which particular XML to generate? Or you need just ANY XML that matches the XSD, with just dummy content?

The .NET Framework contains a complete object model for XSD - in the namespace `System.Xml.Schema`, you can use those classes to load the XSD and get the information you need relatively easy - you'll end up with an `XmlSchemaComplexType` instance with the list of all possible attributes and sub-elements with their types, you can use that to generate your XML.

Comment: Mimo ..Thanks for your help...But i just tried an alternate method where i compiled XSD file using ICodeCompiler. and then serialized the class..anyway thanks for the help..